# Fail to install MySQL in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I had ever installed MySQL in my Linux Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, but it had some problem, then I removed it.
However I wanted to install back again, so I followed this code to uninstall

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/mysql
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I want install again by:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Then, some error code come up:

```
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-community-client (8.0.27-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-client (8.0.27-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.27-1ubuntu18.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.27-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
/usr/bin/mandb: can't write to /var/cache/man/9261: No space left on device
/usr/bin/mandb: can't create index cache /var/cache/man/9261: No space left on device
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I use this:

```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

this result show up:

```
 mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-12-29 19:24:39 CST; 16min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Main PID: 7425 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Server startup in progress"

12月 29 19:24:39 jacky-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
12月 29 19:24:39 jacky-VirtualBox su[7395]: Successful su for mysql by root
12月 29 19:24:39 jacky-VirtualBox su[7395]: + ??? root:mysql
12月 29 19:24:39 jacky-VirtualBox su[7395]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user mysql by (uid=0)
12月 29 19:24:39 jacky-VirtualBox su[7395]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user mysql
12月 29 19:24:39 jacky-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
12月 29 19:24:39 jacky-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
12月 29 19:24:39 jacky-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I had tried to uninstall MySQL again and again, but it didn't work.
Hope guys can give some suggestion.

Comment: no space left on the device `clearly showing a message`. you need to increase space on machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you must reinstall the whole operating system, because you have wrongly partitioned disk.

Or you just have full disk.